# ElectronJS: What's the safest way to load user's local files in the DOM (<video src="C:\...">)?

Tags: security, electron

The application I'm developing will allow users to choose video files via native file chooser or drag and drop. The app will render a card to let the user trim the video, and set an output directory for the trimmed video (using ffmpeg to manage the video manipulation).

I plan on storing the paths to already "queued" or chosen videos in a .json file in appdata to preserve the app's state on close. The only network requests will be outgoing to upload the files to YouTube via https with oauth and won't have any ingoing requests (everything will be packaged with the application with nodeIntegration disabled per the electron security guide)

Is allowing file:// requests via electron's `registerFileProtocol` or `registerURLSchemeAsPrivileged('file')` in my case a security concern? If so, what could some steps to closing said concern be?

Comment: "_files from the user's filesystem_" who inputs the path to those files? "_XSS risk in Electron applications_" who do you suspect could be the source of the attack? How would they inject code in your application? "_the best alternative in terms of security vulnerabilities and performance_" what is your definition of security and performance? While people can certainly sympathise with your concerns, everybody has different use case and definition/expectation, leading to totally different solutions. Without expliciting further your specific case, you might end up with irrelevant answers.

Comment: Hi @ghybs thank you for your suggestions/questions. I've edited my post to be more usecase specific and hopefully provide enough info for a specific and relevant answer. Sorry it was so scant on details, I was trying to be generic which is counter to the idea of asking an SO question.

Comment: This needs more attention.. While I think you somehow need to load the files and as long you're not loading any external files, where the url could be changed it should be okay. I don't know that tough and would like to hear from someone who really knows it!